# insufficient funds for gas * price + value

Tags: node.js, ethereum, web3js

I am attempting to broadcast a constructed transaction for *rinkeby*. *Web3* seems to always return errors, sometimes for

> insufficient funds for gas * price + value

and other times for

> Gas limit too high

```
var Web3 = require("web3")
var web3 = new Web3("https://rinkeby.infura.io/TOKEN")
var privateKey =
  "PRIVATE_KEY"

var tx = {
  chainId: 4,
  from: "22dd8860db83a962e8d2ec734eae62fab63e73ae",
  gas: "128028",
  gasPrice: web3.utils.toWei("0.00000002", "ether"),
  nonce: "0x0",
  to: "0x8a09e76a5255E3d07854647f4DBef7323F98323d",
  value: web3.utils.toWei(".000001", "ether")
}

var signed = web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, privateKey)
web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction).then(console.log)
```

> Unhandled rejection Error: Returned error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value

Comment: Does you increases as limit ? and could you ask this question in ethereum.stackexchange.com .

Comment: The gas value you're proving could be a bit high. Default value for ETH transactions vary but commonly is 21000 and for token transfers is around 36505 on ropsten network.

Answer (score 2):

Check your gas price.

The error is caused when your final calculated gas price + value (amount you intend to transfer) is greater than the amount of ether you have in your account.

So the possible solutions are

1. check your gas price it may be absurdly high (probably by mistake)
2. If you are in test network add ethers to your account, or same in main net.

Answer (score 1):

The error is likely due to an insufficiency of ETH in your rinkeby test-net wallet. I recommend using a faucet to add eth to the wallet.

I used this one: https://rinkebyfaucet.com/